# How to use DXA ContentProvider class to Obtain PageModel and Entities in a SpringBoot application

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-2.0, spring

We have implemented an API that we are going to use in our mobile applications, what we are trying to do is to re-use our Entities classes that we created for our Web applications, but when we are trying to use ContentProvider.getPageModel or ContentProvider.getEntityModel we are having a problem when StaticContentResolver calls _getStaticContentFile we get an error because webApplicationContext.getServletContext().getRealPath() returns null, this seems to happen because this is a springBoot project and not a webapplication, so the application doesn't have the folder WEBINF, is there a work around to make DXA ContentProvider compatible with SpringBoot project?